# Convert two-sided document into single-sided with page numbers, header and footer

Tags: fancyhdr, double-sided, preamble, single-sided

I want to convert my thesis into a single-sided document with page numbers, header and footer.

```
\documentclass[twosided,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\itshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}

\let\headruleORIG\headrule
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\color{dark-gray}\headruleORIG}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3 pt}
\let\footruleORIG\footrule
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\color{dark-gray}\footruleORIG}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\begin{document}
Title page here
Declaration here
Abstract here
TOC
main matter
Bibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't you just replace `twosided` with `oneside` in the first line?

Comment: But it does not change page numbering as well as headers and footers.

Comment: Oh right, you'll also have to remove the `E` and `O` options when you use `\fancyfoot` and `\fancyhead`. Also should only specify either `L` or `R`, not both, otherwise both sides will have page numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I applied the adjustments I suggested in my comments in the below example. Does it look like what you expect? I added some placeholder text to demonstrate the header and footer. Also, I couldn't figure out how to use `\color{dark-gray}`, so I replaced it with `\color{darkgray}` which is defined in the `xcolor` package.

```latex
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\itshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\let\headruleORIG\headrule
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\color{darkgray}\headruleORIG}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\let\footruleORIG\footrule
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\color{darkgray}\footruleORIG}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.3pt}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Testing a}
\lipsum[1-6]
\section{Testing a1}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter{Testing b}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of output of above latex code]

Comment: A Big Thankyou!

Comment: @Sajnav.h [Comments are generally reserved for clarification, or adding important information related to the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). I appreciate the "thank you", but simply accepting the answer would be preferable.